# Custom wordpress post type with parents

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages, custom-taxonomy

First of all, this is a very beginner type of question so I hope you understand my idiocy.

I would like to create a WordPress theme similar to https://www.novelfull.com where there is a parent post(which is a book post) with all the child posts (the chapters of that book) in it. It is possible to make a WordPress category to book post and the WordPress post as its chapter posts, but I would like to have something more dedicated, like a custom post type that accepts children posts or something similar if it exists, (as long as it adds children posts(chapters) to parent post(books) automatically when I add them). Is there a feature like this in WordPress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is quite well documented here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/

To get you started, paste the following code in your functions.php or even better, create a custom plugin.

```
    function create_book() {
  register_post_type( 'book',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Books' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'book' ),
        'add_new' => _x('Add book', 'book'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add book'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit book'),
        'new_item' => __('New book'),
        'view_item' => __('View book'),
        'search_items' => __('Search book'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Niets gevonden in de prullenbak'),
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-book-alt',
      'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'book', 'with_front' => true ),
      'menu_position' => 3,
      'hierarchical' => true,
      'supports' => array(
                'title',
                'page-attributes',
                'thumbnail',
                'editor',
                'excerpt',
                'author',
                'comments',
                'custom-fields',
            ),
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_book' );
```

Comment: I see now, this page-attribute is the key. As without it in the supports, you can't add what's parent and whats child.

Comment: True, and the hierarchal argument is important too